# How do I install Groovy on an Ubuntu system for all users?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to install Groovy for all users on an Ubuntu system. Apparently the correct way to install Groovy is to use http://sdkman.io/ but following those instructions the software is only installed for the root user. What are you intended to do?

Comment: Why not simply install it from the universe repo? If you need something newer, binary and source zips are available. `sdkman` is meant to allow the user to install what he needs into his own environment.

Comment: I originally tried installing from the universe repo but I got errors running `apt-get update` on it, leading me to believe it was no longer supported.

Answer (score 3):

I would check the paragraph: Installing to a Custom Location in the 
[install documentation](http://sdkman.io/install.html).

After you install it, say in `/usr/local/sdkman`, it gets a matter to invoke:

```
source "/usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

for any user login: it can be done putting a custom bash init file in

```
/etc/profile.d/
```

http://sdkman.io/install.html

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install groovy
```

Works fine to me in Ubuntu 16.04.3

Answer (score 0):

On recent Ubuntu versions (works on Ubuntu 19.10) Groovy can be installed with [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/install/groovy/ubuntu):

```
sudo snap install groovy --classic
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:groovy-dev/groovy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install groovy
```

Let me know how that works for you.